# GeoCoordinateWatcher doesn't give the latest data when run in the background with ScheduledTaskAgent

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

GeoCoordinateWatcher class when used from a ScheduledTaskAgent does not give live GPS data. Though GeoCoordinateWatcher  object's PositionChanged event gets fired more than twice it shows the same old data every time. I have kept the threshold as 0.0 .

But the same GeoCoordinateWatcher  object's PositionChanged event from UI gets fired more than twice and gives the latest data about location in the last PositionChanged event.

Any idea how to fix this in ScheduledTaskAgent which gets fired for every 30 mins.

Code :

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
watcher.MovementThreshold = 0.0;
watcher.Start();
watcher.PositionChanged += _watcher_PositionChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "fix"?

[The API works as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

GeoCoordinateWatcher API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device, is supported for use in background agents, but it uses a cached location value instead of real-time data. The cached location value is updated by the device every 15 minutes.